# Cannot access hasura with Firebase jwt token

Tags: firebase, jwt, authorization, hasura

Cannot set up role based access to data...
Following the documentation for Firebase have set Heroku Config Var:

```
{
    "type":"RS256",
    "jwk_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com",
    "audience": "geosystem-2021",
    "issuer": "https://securetoken.google.com/geosystem-2021"
}
```

And sending from Apollo Client Header:

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
```

The token checked on `https://jwt.io/` contains claims:

```
"https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
    "x-hasura-default-role": "biuro",
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": [
      "biuro"
    ],
    "x-hasura-user-id": "ytBVYInCbCghON3Xv4gXUq9iXsn1"
  },
```

And still on Hasura API Explorer with selected header : `Authorization Bearer oad098sadTOKEN_HERE` getting error:

```
x-hasura-admin-secret/x-hasura-access-key required, but not found
```

on client:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): x-hasura-admin-secret/x-hasura-access-key required, but not found
```

With `x-hasura-admin-secret` everything is working fine but all tables are available, not the ones meant for my user role...
What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to wrong configuration in Hasura-Heroku panel.

Comment: Thank you. This answer actually helped me realize I had the wrong project URL in my code.